# python: get list of running roscores URIs

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In python is there a way to get a list of URIs of the roscores that are running in a machine ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356265/python:-get-list-of-running-roscores-uris/) by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit 3: Ok, so making a bunch of assumptions and using `psutil` in Python we can put something like this together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psutil

masters = [p for p in psutil.process_iter() if 'rosmaster' in p.name()]
for m in masters:
    # assume there is only one connection per process which is LISTENing
    # TODO: make this more robust, do some checking, etc
    ip, port = [c.laddr for c in m.connections() if c.status == 'LISTEN'][0]
    print ("Master (pid: {}), URI: http://{}:{}".format(m.pid, ip, port))
```

Output on a machine running two masters (one on the standard port, the other on `11411`):

```
Master (pid: 14735), URI: http://0.0.0.0:11311
Master (pid: 15018), URI: http://0.0.0.0:11411
```

The assumptions I'm making here:

1. the process is actually called `rosmaster`
2. it's listening on only a single port
3. that port is the XML RPC port

<del>I also don't know whether this will see `roscore`s not started by your own `$USER`.</del>

It sees them, but as expected, as `$USER` doesn't have the necessary rights, you get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "list_rosmasters.py", line 7, in <module>
  listen_ports = [c.laddr for c in m.connections() if c.status == 'LISTEN']
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 1033, in connections
  return self._proc.connections(kind)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 821, in wrapper
  raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._name)
psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=15557, name='rosmaster')
```

That would be the same limitation as running `netstat` without `sudo`.

---

Edit 2:

> I'm looking for a workaround either with subprocess or linux commands in general that may give a list or roscore that are available and then to do some hardcoding for geting a list of the URIs but it's not clear how to find them. somehow there should be a way to find processes named roscore and get their information

On Linux you might be able to use a combination of `pgrep roscore` (which outputs the PIDs) and then `netstat -antp` and `grep` for the PID. Two "problems":

1. with `-p` you will only see the PIDs/names of the processes your `$USER` started. To see all processes, you'd have to run `netstat` as `root`
2. the PID `pgrep roscore` prints is not the PID which is associated with the XML-RPC port opened by `roscore` (ie: `11311`)

You may need to do some additional work with `ps` or some other tool to find out the process group and filter on those PIDs.

---

Edit: what you could maybe look at is [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie) and the way it "discovers" running masters.

---

No, there is no such API.

> is there a way to get a list of URIs of the roscores that are running in a machine ?

you could probably put together a bit of Python which could do this, but it would be custom code and probably come down to just trying to connect to a nr of ports.

Every ROS Master is a stand-alone program. There is no central registry which keeps track of which are running or where.

Finally:

> roscores that are running in a machine

It's not too common to have multiple masters running on a single machine actually.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on 2020-07-02**:
I'm looking for a workaround either with subprocess or linux commands in general that may give a list or roscore that are available and then to do some hardcoding for geting a list of the URIs but it's not clear how to find them. somehow there should be a way to find processes named roscore and get their information

**Comment by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on 2020-07-02**:
so any hack would still solve my problem

**Comment by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on 2020-07-02**:
it says psutil.AccessDenied (pid=1124, name='rosmaster') for m.connections()

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-02**:
Please read the last part of `Edit 3`.